# Finding the height of a bridge when given angles of depression and length

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Consider a bridge that is $140$ metres long. From the ends of the bridge, the angles of depression of a point on the ground under the bridge are $41^\circ$ and $48^\circ$. How high is the bridge above the ground to the nearest metre?

My solution:

We must use a system of equations. There are two triangles with height $h$, one of which has an angle of elevation $41^\circ$ and the other $48^\circ$. If we consider $x$ and $y$ to be the bases of the triangles, we have the following system:

$x+y=140$

$x(\tan(41^\circ)) = y\tan(48^\circ)$

If we solve the following system, we get:

$x=78.5321535$

We can use this to find $h$:

$h=x\tan(41^\circ)$

Therefore, $h=68$ metres

This answer is not the official one at all, and I'm not sure where the fault in my solution is. Can someone point it out?

Comment: How is the official answer different?

Comment: The official answer is 60 metres, and no explanation is given as to how it was reached.

Comment: Fouad, I agree with your result. I rounded to 4 decimals (e.g. $x \cong 78.5312$), and I got $h \cong 68.267$ at the end.

Comment: I also found the numbers work out with $x=78.5321535$ and height is then approximately $68.27$ for both ends. Maybe it is a misprint in the official solution.

Comment: Does the text of the question clearly state the angles as 41 and 48? The reason I ask is if the second angle was 40 instead of 48 then you would get their answer

Comment: Question solved here :https://www.jiskha.com/questions/1383156/a-bridge-is-140m-long-from-the-ends-of-the-bridge-the-angles-of-depression-of-a-point-on. States that your answer is almost correct($68.3$). I'm guessing this is an IGCSE question so I assume the answer should be to $3$sf hence the "almost".

Comment: "*This answer is not the official one at all*" I disagree with the qualifier "at all": 68 and 60 are arguably the same value, just to different precision (1 significant figure versus 2).